# minitest + capybara how to do save_and_open_page when there is an error

Tags: ruby, capybara, minitest

When using `rspec` I usually do something like:

```
if ENV['OPEN_ERRORS']
  shown_error_pages = 0

  config.after :each do
    if RSpec.current_example.exception != nil and shown_error_pages == 0
      shown_error_pages += 1
      save_and_open_page
    end
  end
end
```

e.g. `OPEN_ERRORS=1 bundle exec rspec`

How can I do something like this with minitest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a teardown or after_teardown block by checking !passed?

The capybara-screenshot gem provides this behavior and is compatible with both RSpec and minitest, you can see how it implements the behavior here - https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot/blob/master/lib/capybara-screenshot/minitest.rb